# How to failed one Jenkins job if another Jenkins job also failed?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-cli

I need help in Jenkins, I have this unique requirement:
I have two Jenkins jobs, **Job-A** and **Job-B**, and **Job-A** triggers the **Job-B** and waits to finish the **Job-B** and then checks its complete status(Success or Failed), if **Job-B** '**Failed**' then **Job-A** also posts '**Failed**' status, or if **Job-B** '**Success**' then **Job-A** also posts '**Success**' status.

How do I do this, how do I check the '**complete status**' of another Jenkins job from within a Jenkins job?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jenkins scripted pipeline, It would be something like this :

```
node() {
  try {
    ....
    def jobB = build(job: jobName,parameters: [])
    def jobBStatus = jobB.getResult()

    if(jobBStatus == "failed") {
      throw new RuntimeException("Downstream job-b failed with reason ...");
    }
    ...
  }catch(Exception e) {
    throw e
  }
}
```

If you are using Jenkins declarative pipeline, there is a pre-build groovy method available to be used

```
pipeline {
  agent any;
  .....//steps, stage , script if any
  
    def jobB = build(job: jobName,parameters: [])
    def jobBStatus = jobB.getResult()

    if(jobBStatus == "failed") {
      error("Downstream job-b failed with reason ...")
    }

}
```

Comment: @Patel, thanks for your reply
I should've mentioned that I am new to Jenkins, never used pipeline. I have following questions:
1. should I add this pipeline script in Job-A 'Configuration' part? 
2. Does the call to getResult() in 'jobB.getResult()' blocking? because we need to wait until jobB is finished, please explain.

Comment: Sounds like you are using Jenkins 1 (Jobs) when what you need is Jenkins 2 (pipelines).  Pipelines are tailor-made for the problem you are having, but you are going to have to get educated.  Good luck.

Comment: the logic is to from the job you are triggering another job